# Getting Invalid Double Exception though there is no double variable used

Tags: android, gson, double

Hello I am using Gson parser, in my class there is no double variable used though I am getting Invalid Double Exception, where the value comes as emtpty string but there is no double variable in my class structure.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: post logcat ...

Comment: logcat is just showing invalid double : ""

Comment: please check full stacktrace of the exception . Is It showing just a single line ? And post your related code too

Comment: : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:227)
:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:217)
:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140170/gson-jsonsyntaxexception-java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-double) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672456/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-double)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to handle response using `Gson` and your **pojo class model** has datatype `Double` but response returns value as "" which is `String` as default value.

> Please make your default value as 0 for the same field and your problem will get resolved. If there is a backend guy working for APIs ask him to set default value as 0 for such fields.